# How did this string get turned to a number?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I'm running

```
var degFahren = (prompt("Enter the degrees fahrenheit"));
var degCent;

degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);
document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 fahrenheit is " + degCent + "\xB0    centigrade<br/>");

if (degCent <0) {
document.write("That's below the freezing point of water!");
}
if (degCent >= 100) {
document.write("That's above the boiling point of water!");
}
```

The string being turned into a number is what I wanted, but why and how did it happen? I never declared a parseFloat or wrapped a Number around the Prompt

Comment: It happened automatically at the point you used degF in the `degC` calculation.

Comment: this happen because its inside calculation formula inside `degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);` delete this line and its should return as string :)

Comment: I assume `degFahren` is the string that got turned?

Comment: https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `-`, javascript tries to interpret the variable as a number. This is in contrast to `+`, where it will do different operations if the variable is a string or a number (concat vs. addition).

This kind of thing happens with javascript all the time.

Examples:

```
"1" - 1 // outputs 0
"a" - 1 // NaN
"1" + 1 // "11"
1 + 1   // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the line:

```
degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);
```

The short answer is that when you use the `-` operator on `degFahren` JavaScript turns it into a number automatically and then the result of your operation (another number) is put in `degCent`.

The long answer is in [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)